# How to insert two associated records into two tables?

Tags: mysql, database

I'd like to insert two associated records into two tables. One record is associated with another record by a foreign key.

e.g. I have two records:

```
product (productid,product_name,category_id)
category (category_id,category_name)
```

But the `category_id` is `auto_increment`. So I don't know its value until I insert it into the category table. So here I have to invoke three sql queries, one is to insert record into category table, second is retrieval the category_id, the last sql query is to insert record into product table.

Overall, it seems the performance will not be good because of executing three sql queries. I just want to know is there any best practice for this scenario ? Thanks

Jeff Zhang

Comment: Which programming language/access library are you using? PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html) how you can get the last inserted unique id

> When a new AUTO_INCREMENT value has
>   been generated, you can also obtain it
>   by executing a SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
>   statement with mysql_query() and
>   retrieving the value from the result
>   set returned by the statement.

Also note that

> For LAST_INSERT_ID(), the most
>   recently generated ID is maintained in
>   the server on a **per-connection** basis

Comment: One problem is that if there's another insert at the same time, then maybe I will the wrong last_insert_id. Does it mean that I need to lock the whole table ?

Comment: MySQL will handle the auto_increment of the ids properly. Even if two insert statements are inserted exactly at the same time MySQL will be able to differentiate between that. And you need the last auto incremented id to to insert to another table as a foreign key, right? That is the advantage of calling `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. It works **per-connection basis**. So it doesn't matter if 1000 records were inserted at the same time, you will ALWAYS get the auto increment id of the current connection to be used as a foreign key.

Comment: Ranhirus, Do you mean I need to put these steps in one transaction to make sure that they are using the same connection ?

Comment: My guess is that you don't have to worry about anything. it doesn't matter whether you insert to the other table in another connection but you should call LAST_INSERT_ID in the same connection. Or did I misunderstand you ?

Comment: Because I am using spring jdbc which has encapsulate all the details

Comment: I am sorry, I have no idea how things would change if you use spring jdbc :S

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to invoke SQL to see the inserted autoincrement value, you can use [last_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) function.